# Launcher icons are invisible after upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade, launcher, icons

I am re-purposing an old laptop.  I installed 11.10 on it and then immediately upgraded to 12.04.  (I could not directly install 12.04 as my system does not support PAE.)

When my system was (briefly) 11.10, the desktop appeared as expected.  However, after the upgrade to 12.04, the icons in the launcher area are invisible.  If I hover over the spot where the icon should be the little popup window showing the tool's name appears, and I can click to invoke the tool.  I just cannot see the icons.

[image]

The icons do appear as expected in other contexts, for example in the Home folder and in Dash Home.

My theme is "Ambiance (default)"

I do not have a ~/.icons folder.

This is the top level contents of /usr/share/icons:

> ```
> default
> DMZ-Black
> DMZ-White
> gnome
> handhelds
> hicolor
> HighContrast
> HighContrastInverse
> Humanity
> Humanity-Dark
> locolor
> LoginIcons
> LowContrast
> redglass
> ubuntu-mono-dark
> ubuntu-mono-light
> unity-icon-theme
> whiteglass
> ```

(Sorry for the poor formatting, can't get it to show in list.)

I suspect that the launcher isn't looking for the icons in the right place, but I don't know how to confirm that, or how to correct.

This is my first foray into Linux, although I used to use Unix a few decades ago.  This doesn't look much like my old Sun workstation, though!

Does anyone have any suggestions or insights for me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st try reset your unity by using this command

```
unity --reset
```

Rebuilt icon package

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Unity-icon-theme'
```

Other default icon package

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Ubuntu-mono-dark' 

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Ubuntu-mono-light'
```

Comment: I have tried "uniti --reset".  It made no difference.

Comment: Will I need to restart after doing gsettings?

Comment: nope... is there any different? i've update my answer, please try others.

Comment: I've tried all 3 gsettings.  No change.

Comment: Please refer this if you want to reinstall unity http://penreturns.rc.my/2012/02/how-to-restore-missing-unity-launcher.html

Comment: Ok, I'll check that out.  However I should mention that the launcher is not missing, only the icons are missing.

Comment: As an aside, do you know why my image file doesn't appear in my post?

Comment: Ok,tried 'sudo apt-get install reinstall unity && sudo restart'.  No change.

Comment: give me your link image

Comment: I don't know how to give it to you, as i don't know how to upload it.  In my post, i clicked on the 'img' link, and then browsed to the image on my local machine.

Comment: ok try upload to this site and give me the link http://imgur.com/

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Hi93b.jpg

Comment: Have you try on Ubuntu 2D?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  This computer is very old, I assumed that while ubuntu was installing it would choose 2D over 3D.  I don't recall being asked to choose between them.

Comment: At login screen, after boot, you will prompt password, click ubuntu logo and choose ubuntu 2D.

Comment: I installed 2D as described here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity2D (except I substituted 'ppa' for'staging').  I restarted.  I was logged in automatically.  I logged out.  One the login screen I was not presented with an option for using 2D.

Comment: Ah ha! I now see that you said I should click on the ubuntu logo to choose 2D.  I have done that.  I am now using 2d (verified via $DESKTOP_SESSION), and now I can see the icons in the launcher!

Comment: Ahaaa... Happy Ubuntu!